# Does an if statement create a local scope?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scope

I am currently reading through some javascript tutorials and I came upon this bit of example code from here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

```
if (hour < 18) {
greeting = "Good day";
```

}

In this example, the greeting variable is not prefixed with a var statement. Now I looked up what this means, and my understanding is that it causes java script to look to a higher scope, if no variable is discovered by the global scope it creates it.

So is this tutorial doing this because the if statement's block is a local environment? If so does that mean that if I were to have some code that looked like this:

```
if (condition){var x=10};
else {var x=5};
```

then there would still be no global variable x for me to call?

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript (ES5), an `if` statement does not create a local scope when declaring with `var`. Local scope is created with a function.

Answer (score 1):

W3Schools is notorious for using bad practices in their code samples, and you've found one example of this. They are creating a globally-scoped variable.

Blocks will only create a local scope for variables declared with the new [`let` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). If you're using an older version of JavaScript, or if you're using the `var` keyword, then the variable is scoped to the innermost `function` that the variable is declared in.

Variables declared via `var` outside of any function are scoped to the `window` (global) scope.

```js
{
  var x = "hello world";
}
document.getElementById("var-value").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<span id="var-value"></span>
```

In the above snippet, if you replaced `var` with `let`, it would produce an error because `x` is undefined.

```js
{
  let x = "hello world";
}
document.getElementById("var-value").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<span id="var-value"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to get the value of x outside of the if..else. This is due to JavaScript having function scope rather than block. I created a JSFiddle of your example, which can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/h4gjb8mt/

Example:

```
var condition = true;

if (condition) {
    var x=10;
}
else {
    var x=5;
}

console.log(x);
```